# A Bessel related question - What is the M(u,v,phi) function?

Tags: reference-request, special-functions

I have came across a function, written as M(u,v,phi), where it is defined as: 
$$
= 1/2 \pi * \int_0^\infty e^{(u \cos(\theta)} * e^{(v \cos(2(\theta + \phi)}   d(\theta) 
$$

To my knowledge, this M(.,.,.) function presents properties related to the Bessel functions, where M(u,0,phi) = I_0(u) , and M(0,v,phi) = I_0(v). and I_0(.) is the modified Bessel function of the first kind and order zero.

My wonders are whether is there any resource I can read to get to deal with this function; What is it ? How to Integrate it ? Any more information or references would be useful.

Thank You in Advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this "sort" of functions gives some generalization of modified Bessel functions.

"Sort", because I'm not sure that you copied it correctly: guess the limits of the integral should be slightly different (maybe $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cdot \ \mathrm d\theta$).

Anyways, I you are interested in different modifications of Bessel functions then you should resort to so table of integrals and special functions handbooks, like:

1. [Gradshteyn and Ryzhik's Table of Integrals, Series, and Products.](http://books.google.ru/books/about/Table_of_Integrals_Series_and_Products.html?id=aBgFYxKHUjsC&redir_esc=y)
2. [Frank W. J. Olver NIST Handbook of Mathematical Functions](http://books.google.ru/books?id=3I15Ph1Qf38C&dq=NIST%20Handbook%20of%20Mathematical%20Functions&hl=ru&source=gbs_navlinks_s)
3. [A. P. Prudnikov, Yu. A. Brychkov and O. I. Marichev Integrals & Series (V.1-3)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/2881240976)
4. [Milton Abramowitz, Irene A. Stegun Handbook of Mathematical Functions: With Formulas, Graphs, and Mathematical Tables](http://books.google.ru/books?id=MtU8uP7XMvoC&dq=Handbook%20of%20Mathematical%20Functions:%20with%20Formulas,%20Graphs,%20and%20Mathematical%20Tables&hl=ru&source=gbs_navlinks_s)
5. [NIST Digital Library of Mathematical Functions](http://dlmf.nist.gov/)
6. [G. N. Watson A Treatise on the Theory of Bessel Functions](http://books.google.ru/books/about/A_Treatise_on_the_Theory_of_Bessel_Funct.html?id=Mlk3FrNoEVoC&redir_esc=y)

And many, many more.